# Why is nothing drawn in PyGame at all?

Tags: python, pygame, rectangles

i have started a new project in python using pygame and for the background i want the bottom half filled with gray and the top black. i have used rect drawing in projects before but for some reason it seems to be broken? i don't know what i am doing wrong. the weirdest thing is that the result is different every time i run the program. sometimes there is only a black screen and sometimes a gray rectangle covers part of the screen, but never half of the screen.

```py
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

DISPLAY=pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
pygame.display.set_caption("thing")
pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, (200,200,200), pygame.Rect(0,400,800,400))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: Where do you update the display? ( [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update()) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip()))

Comment: Use this : pygame.display.update()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update the display.
You are actually drawing on a [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) object. If you draw on the *Surface* associated to the PyGame display, this is not immediately visible in the display. The changes become visibel, when the display is updated with either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip).

See [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip):

> This will update the contents of the entire display.

While `pygame.display.flip()` will update the contents of the entire display, `pygame.display.update()` allows updating only a portion of the screen to updated, instead of the entire area. `pygame.display.update()` is an optimized version of `pygame.display.flip()` for software displays, but doesn't work for hardware accelerated displays.

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (draw all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
- limit frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
pygame.display.set_caption("thing")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    # handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            run = False

    # clear display
    DISPLAY.fill(0)

    # draw scene
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, (200,200,200), pygame.Rect(0,400,800,400))

    # update display
    pygame.display.flip()

    # limit frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

<kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-MinimalApplicationLoop](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-MinimalApplicationLoop#main.py)</kbd> See also [Event and application loop](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_event_and_application_loop.md)

Answer (score 0):

simply change your code to:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

DISPLAY=pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
pygame.display.set_caption("thing")
pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, (200,200,200), pygame.Rect(0,400,800,400))
pygame.display.flip() #Refreshing screen

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

it should help